# Eclipse JSF autocompletar bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Dispongo de un proyecto de JSF que actualmente esta utilizando `Primefaces`, `JSF` y `Hibernate`. Todos los tags que declaro se me autocompletan sin problemas utilizando `CTRL + SPACE` en `Eclipse`.

```
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
```

El problema lo tengo en programar partes que estén utilizando `Beans` en `.XHTML`:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{beanCliente.datosPersonales.nif}" />
```

Ninguna de las propiedades del `beanCliente` se me autocompletan utilizando en `CTRL + SPACE`, pero al compilar y probar el código si que funciona correctamente.

Es posible autocompletar los `beans` de un `.XHTML`?

Answer (score 1):

Para poder usar de esa forma el eclipse con JSF, instala el plugin de jboss. Si mal no recuerdo es JBoos Tools. De acuerdo a la version del eclipse que tengas (Luna, Kepler, Mars, etc).

Para instalar el plugin, sigue este tutorial: http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/installation.html

Me comentas como te fue. Saludos